# Fine Uploader, how can I manage scaled images names and extensions on client side?

Tags: image, fine-uploader

I need to upload only scaled images on the server.
For original + scaled images docs say:

> The code above will result in Fine Uploader generating and uploading 2 scaled versions of each user-submitted image file. The original, along with the 2 scaled versions, will appear in the UI's file list as well. If the user submits a PNG named "image.png", that will be submitted, along with another file named "image (small).png", and "image (medium).png".

I guess it's the same for only scaled version, but the file I'm receiving on server side is just named `blob` without any extension!

I'm using this script

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
...
scaling: {
    sendOriginal: false,

    sizes: [
        {name: "scaled", maxSize: 1280}
    ]
}
```

});

How can I set at least the original file extension (and maybe the name aswell) to the blob file from the client side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the "Notices" section on that same doc page:

> The scaled file names will be sent with the upload request as the qqfilename parameter. Be sure to read this parameter when naming your file server-side.

Comment: Thanks Ray, so there is not any chance to rename the scaled blob image on client side? That would make my life much easier instead of modify serverside script :)

Comment: You can modify the suffix using the name property, as you are already doing. Of course the original file name can be modified too using the setName API method, which will carry over to the scaled image uploads too.

Comment: Could you make an example please? That would be really helpful, i've tried many ways but didn't get them working so far. Thanks.

Comment: Just realized now you are the library developer, congrats, great work!